# Amazon Redshift - Fetch Cursor Commands are hanging on Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

We have a Redshift Cluster with performance issues. When running certain queries on a cluster, there is an intermediary step in the query plan **Fetch 200 in "SQL_CUR7"**. This step is causing the query to hang and jams up the cluster. We haven't defined this cursor and it seems like it's pre-defined by Redshift. Does anybody know what this type of cursor does? and if this could be the cause of our performance issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That name, SQL_CUR7, looks like the naming used by Tableau but it could be from other tools or users that use the same naming or are copying.  Typically Tableau would fetch 10,000 rows at a time so it may not be Tableau.  The point is that FETCH isn't your problem - it's the likely query that is behind the fetch.

Let start with some background.  When you run a query (select ...) the results of that query are sent back to you - all of them, no matter how big.  The amount of data that can come from Redshift can drown smaller computers and brown out networks.  Instead a "cursor" can be declared and the results of the query can be temporarily stored there (on the Redshift leader node in this case).  The contents of the cursor are read by the FETCH command which pulls a specified number of rows out.  This way the reader is not overwhelmed with more data than it can handle.  Fetches can be repeated until all the rows of the cursor are read.

A cursor is defined by the DECLARE statement which also specifies the query to be run to fill the cursor.  However, the query isn't run until the first FETCH of the cursor happens.  Subsequent fetches just pull more data that was populated in the cursor when the first FETCH is executed.  The downside of this is that is LOOKS LIKE the fetch is the thing running which doesn't tell you much about what is happening.  It's the SQL defined in the DECLARE statement that is being run and you need to find out what this SQL is to find out what is going on.

Tracing this back isn't too difficult.  A cursor only lives for the length of time that the transaction is open.  This means that the FETCH and the DECLARE are in the same transaction (xid).  So find the xid of the 'Fetch 200 in "SQL_CUR7"' and use this to find all the statements issued in this transaction (xid) in the system table SVL_STATEMENTTEXT.  (Xids can be reused after some time so you may want to only look at a time window around the execution of the fetch.)  You should see a statement that defines "SQL_CUR7" - DECLARE "SQL_CUR7" ... - this is SQL that is running when the fetch happens.

Now that you see this SQL things will likely start to make sense as to why things are getting overloaded.  The query could just be bad and cross joining the world with everything else.  It could be filling up the disks with intermediate results.  The query could be returning a massive amount of data and it is overloading the leader node with data it needs to buffer.  You may need to some diagnostic work but at least now you have the code that needs to be analyzed.